# Adding and removing event listeners when props value has changed

Tags: reactjs

I have a UserComponent everytime the props.isUserSelected boolean value is changed I want to add or remove event listeners. I'm using a useEffect to watch for changes on the props.isUserSelected value. This is working how I want it to.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UserComponent = (props) => {
  const [wrapperEle] = useState(React.createRef());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.isUserSelected === true) {
      // add event listeners
    } else {
      // remove event listeners
    }
  }, [props.isUserSelected]);

  return (
    <div ref={wrapperEle}>
      <div
        id="1"
        ref={canvasEle}
        className={`test`}
        width={props.canvasWidth}
        height={props.canvasHeight}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserComponent;
```

I need to reference a other element in the useEffect for example the wrapperEle I have to add the wrapperEle as a dependency. But this causes the useEffect to execute everytime the wrapper also changes but I just what it to run when the prop.isUserSelected has changed.

Is there anyway to achieve this to only execute when the props.isUserSelected?

Thanks a lot

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.isUserSelected === true) {
      // add event listeners
      const test = wrapperEle.current;
    } else {
      // remove event listeners
    }
}, [props.isUserSelected, wrapperEle]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** how you handle references in **function component** (research `useRef` vs `createRef`).

The possible solution should look like so:

```
const UserComponent = ({ isUserSelected }) => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUserSelected) {
      wrapperRef.current.addEventListener(...);
    } else {
      wrapperRef.current.removeEventListener(...);
    }

    // Cleanup function
    return () => {
      wrapperRef.current.removeEventListener(...);
    };
  }, [isUserSelected]);

  return <div ref={wrapperEle}></div>;
};
```

See [`useRef` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for more examples.

Comment: Right thank you for the pointer, but when I use the wrapperRef in the useEffect I get a warning: 

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'wrapperEle'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

But including the wrapperEle in the useEffect will cause it to run when ever i change the wrapperEle properties later on, but I just want it when isUserSelected is changed

Would i just have to keep the previous value in state and use that to determine whether the value has changed and to add or remove depending.

Comment: It is not true, using `wrapperRef` with `useRef` won't get a warning as its value is persistence all component's lifecycle. You have examples for it in the docs, please read them.

Comment: You are correct appoligies react newbie, thanks for you help